# Square root of cell array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell, sqrt

I have a cell array A={<2x6 double>,<4x6 double>,<16x6 double>} and I want to calculate the square root of all elements of this cell array. for a single matrix, it is so simple to use sqrt but for cell array, is there any solution?
THX in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `arrayfun`:

```
B = arrayfun(@(i) sqrt(A{i}), 1:length(A), 'Uni', 0);
```

Comment: Or just use cellfun: `B = cellfun(@sqrt, A, 'Un', false)`

Comment: very nice ... just a try because i have just learned how to use `arrayfun` 2 days ago :-) upvoted!